# Table View Cell by Cell out of an array

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am new to Swift and as a little Project I would like to create something like a "Choose your own Adventure Game".

I try to achieve this through a TableView in which every Cell contains a Line of the Story out of an Array.

With my current Code on App Start every Cell is generated Instant and is displaying the Strings of the Array - which is correct but I would like to generate every Cell over Time.

Optional: If possible it would be great to show the String in each Cell Char by Char with a delay so the Characters show up one by one with 0.5 Seconds delay - after First String/Cell is completed this way it should generate the second Cell and write out the second String.

Do you have any suggestions how I can achieve this?

Thanks!

Here is my current Code which is not including any functionality for the Delay since I don't know how to manage this :)

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var storyLines = ["Test Cell 1 and so on first cell of many","second cell bla","aaaand third cell sup"]
    var actualTables = 1


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return storyLines.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TxtLine", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = storyLines[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0;
        cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614883-tableview

There is an instance method named **tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:)** in **uitableviewdelegate**. You can override that method and have your table view cell animated. You can refer the code below as an example.

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: tableView.bounds.width, y: 0)

        UIView.animate(
            withDuration: 0.5,
            delay: 0.05 * Double(indexPath.row),
            options: [.curveEaseInOut],
            animations: {
                cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
        })
    }
}
```

And don't forget to set your viewcontroller as delegate to your tableview.

```
tableview.delegate = self
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer! This helped me out really! Still I am a little confused on how to control the flow of the procedure  at all but I will create a new Question for this - Thank you very much again!